# Play music one after each other

Tags: java, android

I am working on a game in Android and i wanted to add a sort of playlist of music. I have about 10 music files and i want to be able to play the second one when the first one has finished and so on. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Android Mediaplayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)
 and use an OnCompletionListener in which you send a message to a handler, from which you pass the next audiofile to the mediaplayer.

**EDIT :**

You do not really need to use a handler. Here is an example of how you could implement it. 
 Save your titles and a counter as member variables:

```
String[] titles = new String[] { "title1.mp3", "title2.mp3", "title3.mp3",
        "title4.mp3" };
int count = 0;
```

And this is how your onCompletion listener would look like:

```
    void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
           mp.stop();
           if (count == titles.length -1) {
               count = 0;
           }
           mp.setDataSource(titles[count]);
           count++;
           mp.prepare(); 
           mp.start();
        }
```